# Checking if proxy is used or not

Tags: python, python-requests, proxy

I want to use proxy with Python web requests. To test if my request is working or not, I send a request to jsonip.com. In the response it returns my real ip instead of the proxy. Also the website providing proxy also says "no activity". Am I connecting to the proxy correctly? Here the code:

```
import time, requests, random
from requests.auth import HTTPProxyAuth
auth = HTTPProxyAuth("muyjgovw", "mtpysgrb3nkj")

def reqs():   
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:107.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/107.0',
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
        # 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'Referer': 'https://www.google.com/',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
        'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
        'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
        'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'cross-site',
        'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
    }
    prox = [{"http": "http://64.137.58.19:6265"}]
    proxies = random.choice(prox)
    response = requests.get('https://jsonip.com/', headers=headers, proxies=proxies)
    print(response.status_code)
    print(response.json())
reqs()
```

[Screenshot of website showing no activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XywSc.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your have to do this to include the proxy

```
import time, requests, random
from requests.auth import HTTPProxyAuth
auth = HTTPProxyAuth("muyjgovw", "mtpysgrb3nkj")

def reqs():   
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:107.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/107.0',
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
        # 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'Referer': 'https://www.google.com/',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
        'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
        'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
        'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'cross-site',
        'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
    }
    prox = [{"http": "http://64.137.58.19:6265",
             "https": "http://64.137.58.19:6265" }]
    proxies = random.choice(prox)
    response = requests.get('https://jsonip.com/', headers=headers, proxies=proxies)
    print(response.status_code)
    print(response.json())
reqs()
```